# NServiceBus and ASP.NET MVC 2: When to use asynchronous controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous, nservicebus

ASP.NET MVC 2 includes the built in feature of [asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx). My question is: Is there any benefits on using the asynchronous controllers to send messages to the bus if I'm not waiting for a reply from the bus?

Microsoft states this in [their async controller documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx#choosing_synchronous_or_asynchronous_action_methods):

> In general, use asynchronous pipelines when the following conditions are true:
>
> The operations are network-bound or I/O-bound instead of CPU-bound.
>
> Testing shows that the blocking operations are a bottleneck in site performance and that IIS
> can service more requests by using asynchronous action methods for these blocking calls.
>
> Parallelism is more important than simplicity of code.
>
> You want to provide a mechanism that lets users cancel a long-running request.

When reading through the list and keeping in mind that we're not excepting any reply from the bus, I'm not seeing any benefits on using the async controllers over the synchronous ones. But is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the response then you don't need async controllers.